# Python 3.2 idle : how do I display two different values on same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
team = ['sean', 'david', 'JK', 'KB', 'nina']

for i in team:
   print(i), print(len(i))
```

Above shows following result:

```
sean
4
david
5
JK
2
KB
2
nina
4
```

but my instruction book shows this:

```
sean 4
david 5
JK 2
KB 2
nina 4
```

how do I get "xxx, y" format? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why does the formatting of OP's code keep changing? If OP wants the print and the for on the same line, why should we object?

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
for i in team:
    print(i, len(i))
```

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
team = ['sean', 'david', 'JK', 'KB', 'nina']
for i in team:
    print("%s, %d" % (i, len(i)))
```

By the way, there's no `i` in team!

Answer (score 3):

Just do this... nice and simple, no "string formatting" needed.

```
team = ['sean', 'david', 'JK', 'KB', 'nina']

for i in team:
   print(i, len(i))
```

if you want comma between, then

```
team = ['sean', 'david', 'JK', 'KB', 'nina']

for i in team:
   print(i, len(i), sep=', ')
```

I know this is late, but it's good for other people to see this by googling in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in team:
    print "%s %s" % (i, len(i))
```

or:

```
for i in team:
    print i + " " + str(len(i))
```

Comment: Python **3** - `print` is a function. And it still works fine, no need to roll the wheel by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Also i think your original code must be :

```
for i in team:
   print(i); print(len(i))
```

instead of :

```
for i in team:
   print(i), print(len(i))
```

and if you want to do that with your code , try this :

```
for i in team:
   print(i,end=','); print(len(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your instruction book mentioned something like:

```
for i in team:
    print i, len(i)
```

which gived the expected output in Python 2 but is no longer valid in Python 3.

The 'direct' replacement in Python 3 is:

```
for i in team:
    print(i, len(i), sep=' ')
```

but you usually use something else like the `%s %d` solution proposed above.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i,j in zip(team,score):
    print i,j
```

Output:

```
0 sean
1 david
2 JK
3 KB
4 nina
```

Comment: Where does `score` comes from ? Also, this syntax does not work in python 3